# Is it ever OK to write an NPM module that sets module.exports to a generator function?

Tags: node.js, npm, ecmascript-harmony

If you want to publish a module that has sequenced IO, is it ever OK to write,

```
./sequenced_actions.js
module.exports = function * () {}
```

Thereby permitting something like,

```
co( function * {
  yield require('./sequenced_actions');
} )();
```

Comment: why not? you can publish whatever you want

Comment: And clearly there are a lot of things you can publish that are horrible ideas.

Comment: well, it's the matter of opinion as you can see. my opinion is: it's ok, but generator-based flow control is not mainstream (yet), so it's may be a bit early. You can wrap it with `co`, and export a function but still you will have to explain users that your package requires 0.10.x and a flag.

Comment: also, it should be `yield *`, even less people know that thing.

Comment: @vkurchatkin `co` takes care of that. if it gets a generatorFunction it does the right thing. A better question would be how Co reacts if you do it the ES6 way with `yield *` I imagine bad things would happen.

Comment: you are right, `co` has a lot of magic baked in. `yield * require('./sequenced_actions')();` also works, though. I think from `co`s perspective it's the same as have all the `yield`s inline, but might be faster.

Comment: completly forgot that I have already done that: https://github.com/vkurchatkin/generator-foreach

Answer (score 1):

if you want your modules to reach the largest audience possible, just write them in promises. hopefully node v0.12 will have native promises, so this will make things easier

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's okay to do that.

Generator function is just an ordinary function under the hood. And since node.js allows an arbitrary value to be exports object of a module, you can export whatever you want there.